# Excel: One axis tick per data point?

Tags: excel, time-series

I have a time series with irregular intervals like this:

[image]

In the visualization, I want one date for each data point, e.g. like this:
[image]

Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: What you can do, is this: right-click your horizontal axis and open the "Format Axis" pane. Inside "Axis Options", you'll see "Axis Type". Set it to "Text axis". However, this will impact the grid area, because now Excel no longer respects the date intervals. Now, you can, in principle, recreate the intervals be adding empty lines within your data set, but this can be a pain, if you have a large data set.

Comment: I already thought that there is no function to do this properly. Now I'm certain - thanks!